# Access Div atrribute Jquery and rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using the [countTimer plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) for a little online exam app. The idea is when the timer reaches zero, I want to redirect the user to a given url (to an action called time_expired in the questions controller). So the url is in the form: `/questions/:id/time_expired`.

In the `show.html.erb` of questions controller, I have the following div element:

```
<div id="count-down" data-url=<%= time_expired_path %> ></div>
```

Its in this div that I display the timer.

Now in my `application.js` file I want to grap the value of the data-url attribute of my div and use expiryUrl to direct to that url.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    myUrl = $("div").attr("data-url");
    alert(myUrl); // Prints undefine
    $('#count-down').countdown({expiryUrl: myUrl, format: 'MS', until: +10)
});
```

Why is the varibale "myUrl" undefined? I can check the value with firebug and there is indeed a url in my div.

Here is the firebug output:

```
<div id="count-down" data-url="/questions/2/time_expired"></div>
```

rails version: 3.2.8
Ruby Version : 1.9.3
Jquery: Jquery rails that comes shipped with rails

Any help and suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
myUrl = $("#count-down").data("url");
```

Comment: I'd also use the id of the element instead of "div" like so: `$("#count-down").data("url")`